# Java adding an object with two parameters to ArrayList

Tags: java

The add method in the ShoppingCart class doesn't work and this is the error:

> The method add(int, Item) in the type ArrayList is not
> applicable for arguments (Product, int)

Is the problem in the method or is it in the Product class?

```
public class Product {
    private int number;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    
    Product(int number, String name, double price) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

```
    private ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    
    public ShoppingCart() {
        
    }
    
    public void add(Product product, int quantity) {
        itemList.add(product, quantity);
    }
    
    public void remove(Product product) {
        itemList.remove(product);
    }
```

```
        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
        Product product_1 = new Product(10, "Bicycle", 500.00);
        Product product_2 = new Product(11, "Energy bar", 1.50);
        Product product_3 = new Product(12, "Water bottle", 6.00);

        cart.add(product_1, 1);
        cart.add(product_2, 5);
        cart.add(product_3, 2);    
        System.out.println(cart);
```

Comment: You cannot do that with a list. You might want to change to `Map<Product, Integer>` or create an `OrderLine` object that holds the product and quantity.

Comment: Ignoring for a moment what it *would* do, what do *you want* `cart.add(product_1, 1);` to do?

Comment: I want it to add 1 quantity of product 1 to the cart. the post is missing Item class and some code from other classes because i couldnt post so much code

Comment: By the way, you can more briefly define your `Product` class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in Java 16+, if immutability is appropriate to your situation. `record Product( int number, String name, double price ) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's `add` method of ArrayList holds single input as a parameter and adds it to the end of the list.

When you are using the following code, this gives you compile-time error:

```
itemList.add(product, quantity);
```

Maybe you want to use [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) which stores data as key-value pair and removes based on the key. If this is the case you could use:

```
  private Map<Product, Integer> itemMaps = new HashMap<>();

  public ShoppingCart() {
        
    }
    
    public void add(Product product, int quantity) {
        itemMaps.add(product, quantity);
    }
    
    public void remove(Product product) {
        itemMaps.remove(product);
    }
```

**Remember:** you want to store an object of Product in your data structure, so you need to use appropriate types at the time of declaration.

Comment: `ArrayList::add` can accept two arguments, when appropriate overloaded method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here

```
itemList.add(product, quantity);
```

you can only add one time to the list. You should move the quantity as a field in the Product.

```
public class Product {
    private int number;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    Product(int number, String name, double price, int quantity) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Then add to the list only product

```
private ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

public ShoppingCart() {
    
}

public void add(Product product) {
    itemList.add(product);
}

public void remove(Product product) {
    itemList.remove(product);
}
```

adding product:

```
ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
Product product_1 = new Product(10, "Bicycle", 500.00, 1);
Product product_2 = new Product(11, "Energy bar", 1.50, 5);
Product product_3 = new Product(12, "Water bottle", 6.00, 2);

cart.add(product_1);
cart.add(product_2);
cart.add(product_3);    
System.out.println(cart);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should read the documentation of the add method on the list.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-

Look at the signature :

> boolean add(E e)

You're using it wrong which explain the error from the compiler because you try to pass your cart object and an integer, which doesn't fit the signature.

I think that you selected the wrong object for your problem.
What you need is a Map and not a List.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

The Map will take a key (in your case your key will be the Product object) associated with a value (in your case  your value will be the quantity).

Also in your code, you want to add a Product object to an ArrayList exepecting an Item object. It will fail as well because the ArrayList is typed differently that what you give to it.

So a proper implementation of your code would be:

private Map<Product, Integer> productQuantity = new HashMap<>();

```
public ShoppingCart() {
    
}

public void add(Product product, int quantity) {
    // You add the product and the quandity here.
    productQuantity.add(product, quantity);
}

public void remove(Product product) {
    productQuantity.remove(product);
}
```

The last point that you need to take care of is implementing 2 methods.
The **equals** and the **hashcode** methods.

If you don't you might have issues with your Map management.
It's very well documented on the internet.

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/java-hashcode-equals-methods/